# ngx-pagination - rendering page very slow

Tags: html, angular, angular6

I am trying to build an application using Nodejs, Angular 6 and SQL. In my database I have more than 80.000 items, and when I try to paginate using `ngx-pagination`, it runs very slow (the `get` from database happens in 15 seconds, but the page is rendered in more that 1,5 minutes)

Here you have a snippet of my code:

.html

```
<table>
    <thead>
    ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let ded of filteredArray | orderBy : key : reverse | { itemsPerPage: crtPage, currentPage: p, totalItems: itemsLength() }"
            <td>{{ ded.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ ded.group }}</td>
            <td>{{ ded.age }}</td>
        <tr>

    </tbody>

    <div class="hint-text">
        <span>
            Showing {{ itemsLength() }} entries.
        </span>
    </div>

<table>
```

.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.refreshItemsList()
}

refreshItemsList() {
    this.dedService.getNNItems().subscribe((res) => {
      this.extractItems(res)
    });
}

extractItems(res) {
    this.filteredArray = res
}

itemsLength() {
    return this.filteredArray.length
}
```

What can I do to render items faster? Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to get 80.000 records in one time? Why? What is the point of "pagination" then?

Comment: I guess it means rendering fewer entries on page, or else it will crash. I render 50 per page. The first page to be rendered always 'waits' for the other pages to load. How can I render only the first page and then wait for the other one by one?

Comment: Do you make one huge request for loading the entire records, or do you make a request per each page? I mean, do you perform pagination only on client-side?

Comment: Yes, only on client-side. I have some filters+search+sort on this table. If I perform server-side pagination, I won't be able to use them anymore, right?

Comment: Filtered and paginated tables are not a simple thing to code, when you're dealing with huge data. You should filter and page both server-side for much better performance.

Comment: I don't think that you will lose those abilities. Fetching 80k entries at once is not a good approach - as stated by @Zak in the answer. I think you should reconsider your approach. Server-side rendering is a "must" here, I think. You could send your `filter + search keyword + sort` data with your request and return relevant items only.

Answer (score 1):

So if you're trying to get the 80k elements and page client side, it's not a good approach. It's using a lot of memory and compute power, each time you refresh.

Take a look at server-side paging : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pagination#server-side-paging

---

Nodejs side you can paginate your results with something like this :

```
var query = "Select * from ?? DESC limit ? OFFSET ?";

//Mention table from where you want to fetch records example-users & send limit and start 

var table = ["your table",LimitNum,startNum];
query = mysql.format(query, table);
connection.query(query, function(err, rest) {
 if(err){
  res.json(err);
}
else{
// Total Count varibale display total Count in Db and data display the records
   res.json("Total Count": totalCount , "data":rest)
}
```

[Source](https://medium.com/@salonimalhotra1ind/pagination-in-node-express-mysql-eda52bf605b7)

Comment: And how can I perform this server-side pagination? I read that article before, but it only says about this parameter `totalItems: res.count` used for ngx-pagination.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yeah the doc is not very detailed server-side. You have to pass the limit per page and the offset to your sql query.
Same for the filters. It's a bit of work.

Comment: Do you have any idea where I can find a good tutorial for server-side pagination?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, there are a lot. Here's one : https://medium.com/@salonimalhotra1ind/pagination-in-node-express-mysql-eda52bf605b7